# How can I draw this figure in Python using turtle? Sorry, new to this

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGWQD.jpg)

Hi, I'm trying to draw this shape using Python turtle for a learning group and I'm completely lost. Please help.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/843953). 
This usually suggests that you need to walk through one of the many brilliant tutorials available online rather than Stack Overflow. 
Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem. 
In this case, I'd suggest breaking down the problem into steps and using the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) to figure each step out.

Comment: Once you have done this, you can ask a _specific_ question about your code / approach, including a [mre]. If you don't even make an attempt, how will you learn? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to start with adding this to a file firsttry.py

```
import turtle, random
basiclength = 10
elementspercircle = 12
colors  = ["red","green","blue","orange","purple","pink","yellow"] 

length = basiclength
angle = 360/elementspercircle

turtle.pensize(5)

def paintingpainter(directionoffset):
  global length
  global angle
  global colors

  for j in range (4):
    for i in range( elementspercircle + 1):
      turtle.color(random.choice(colors))
      turtle.forward(length)
      turtle.left(angle * directionoffset)
      length = length + directionoffset

paintingpainter(1)
turtle.right(angle * 2)
paintingpainter(-1)
```

then start it with

```
python3 firsttry.py
```

Should look similar to the provided image. Understand the codeparts and adpat it to your needs.